# OpenLayers attribute substitution failing on KML file

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, fields-attributes

I'm trying to read in mile markers for a marathon from a KML file and use the MILE attribute to set the label.  My layer code looks like this:

```js
// add layer
mile_markers_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Mile Markers',
   {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: 'Mile_Markers.kml',
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractAttributes: true 
                    //extractStyles:  true
        })
    }),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            style: {
                'fillColor': '#888888',
                'fillOpacity': 1,
                'fontColor': '#000000',
                'fontFamily': 'arial, sans-serif',
                'fontSize': '.9em',
                'fontWeight': 'bold',
                'label': '${MILE}',
                'pointRadius': 8,
                'strokeColor': '#ff0000',
                'strokeWidth': 3
            }
});
```

I looked in Firebug and all the features of the mile_markers_layer have attribute of `MILE` with a value of "1" thru "26" (as expected).

Layer is displayed with a label of `${MILE}` - by this I mean all 26 mile markers are displayed and each has a label of `${MILE}`

I was expecting the value of MILE instead.  I'm a newbie, so I could be doing something extremely stupid.

The offending KML file is at:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxhE8rRos0u1X2ExNldTdWwwWkk

Thanks for the suggestion, but every mile marker ended up with ${MILE.value} for a label.

Comment: Could you share kml file or your live example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `context` property of Style object:

```
options = {
    div: "map",
    zoom: 12,
    center: [-9074392.9993436, 5021122.97485],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
    ]
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);

OpenLayers.Util.extend(
    OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default,
    {
        label: "${getLabel}",
        pointRadius: 15
    }
);

var mystyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
    OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style.default,
    {
        context: {
            getLabel: function(f) {
                return f.attributes.MILE.value;
            }
        }
    }
);

var sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default': mystyle});

var myKML = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "KML layer", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        styleMap: sm,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "Mile_Markers.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()
        })
});
map.addLayer(myKML);
```

See live demo [here](http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/kml-markers.html).

Comment: Thanks drnextgis,  I finally figured out my StackExchange account

Answer (score 1):

The `MILE` attribute is an object `Object { value="3", displayName="MILE"}`

So try doing something like `'label': '${MILE.value}',`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,  but my Stack Exchange account has been reset since I logged in using Google - so this is me, Dennis.

Thanks very much drnextgis, that works.

There is a slightly different example I found at:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-context.html

Once I knew that it was context that I was looking for, it became easier to find some information.

Just as to clarify for those who read this later,  I understand it as:

Since my KML feature attributes are OBJECTS and not simple values, the normal '${}' doesn't work - the symbolizer can't assign an object as a label.

The Style Context specifies replacements for the default feature.attributes used for the symbolizer.  So you get to write a function that can assign the VALUE of the object, for example, or whatever you want.

Thanks again - I'm definitely a struggling newbie, but now I have numbers for mile markers.

Dennis

Comment: drnextgis  I wish I could accept your answer, since it was extremely useful,  but my old account that I put the question in under has been converted to this new user 8894 once I logged in with Google, and I can't get into my old account (same email).   But accept my thanks.