# KML, OpenLayers: attribute imported as string rather than number

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I've used QGIS to save a shapefile (.shp) file as .kml, then used OpenLayers to import it as a OpenLayers.Vector.Layer.

The .kml file consists of a very long series of placemarks like the one shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document><Folder><name>events_a_</name>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#events_a_">
        <SimpleData name="Date">2001-04-15</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Latitude">34.683300000000003</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Longitude">-76.666700000000006</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="state">North Carolina</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="type">Seizure</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="total regs">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="gtycode1">2335384</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="final_date">2005/06/28</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="end_date">2005-06-29</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <Point><coordinates>-76.6667,34.6833</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
```

I add this this file as an OpenLayers.Vector thusly:

```
var cwevents = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('KML', {
        strategies:[new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: './events_kml/civwar_events(a).kml',
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: false,
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });
```

My problem is that attributes whose type I need to be numeric (or datetime) keep being loaded as simple string variables. ('total_regs' will load as ' "2.0000" ' rather than ' 2.000 ' .) This has made it impossible, for example, for me to vary a feature's marker size according to the value of one of its numeric attributes.

1. How do I ensure that OpenLayers loads specific vector feature attributes as a specified data type?
2. How do I change the KML file so that Openlayers is in no doubt about the data type of individual feature attributes.List item
3. Is there any other approach that might help me here?

I am quite new at OpenLayers.

---

The KML sample file supplied by @user30184 in the answer below might be a quickest way of isolating whatever I'm failing to do in OpenLayers.

If anyone can add this kml file as a vector layer to an OpenLayers map, with the "b" and "c" attributes being correctly read-in as a numeric data type (int, float, anything) rather than as string, can you show the JavaScript you used to add the layer?

The way I added the layer (in the second code block above) has been essentially the same one I've found in the examples in two books and the web. The only variations have been to properties or strategies ("maxDepth:", "extractStyles", "strategies:") that have no effect on the correctly importing the data type.

Alternatively, do you know of a vector-layer format (geojson?) where this problem definitely does not occur?

That might be the most efficient way of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was fretting about strings and floats because I was trying to make the radius of circle-markers proportional to an attribute value in my kml layer's features. The OpenLayers tutorial examples I was following all used toy vector layers added manually as part of the map's html, where the numeric values were indeed entered and were returned (when you looked them up in the Firebug console) as numbers. This made it simple, in these examples, to say that all you needed to do was to a style map with something like, in my case, 'pointRadius: "${total_regs}"' .

Now, when I tried this no markers were returned at all, and, as near as I could see it, this was because, instead of those nice unquotation-marked numbers I saw in the examples, my map was loading the total_regs feature attribute as a string. I then tried to use for-loops to pass these attributes thru' a javascript Number(), before I decided to ask the question on this site.

I found the solution while looking up the posts on the "related questions" sidebar. It's here, [OpenLayers attribute substitution failing on KML file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29584/openlayers-attribute-substitution-failing-on-kml-file?rq=1) , with the key being this:

```
The MILE attribute is an object Object { value="3", displayName="MILE"}
So try doing something like 'label': '${MILE.value}',
```

If anyone's planning to do an OpenLayers tutorial, I might suggest that there's a need for styling examples that load external data rather than, to quote two otherwise really excellent introductory books:

In addition, we are setting in each feature, a couple of attributes (radius and temp)  with random values:

```
    // Add random attributes
    var radius = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 4);
    var temp = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
    pointFeature.attributes.radius = radius;
    pointFeature.attributes.temp = temp;
```

or

Let's demonstrate how to use attribute replacement to change the style of features based on their attribute.

Make a copy of the previous example. We'll be changing it slightly to demonstrate attribute replacement. To do so, we'll first need to give our features some attributes that we can access. Modify the addFeature code in the for loop to add attributes as follows:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ 
    vector_layer.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector( 
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( 
            (Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 180), 
            (Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) - 90) 
        ), 
        { 
            //Attributes go here 
            size: 5 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)), 
            label: 'F' + i, 
            strokeWidth: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) 
        } 
    )]); 
}
```

Now, we just need to modify the vector_style style object to include attribute replacements so we can use the size, label, and strokeWidth properties of the features we just created.

Answer (score 2):

I created a shapefile with attributes of type string, integer, double, and date. Then I converted the shapefile into KML with GDAL 2.0-dev version.

```
ogr2ogr -f kml type.kml typetest.shp
```

Resulting KML file contains schema definitions in the end of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document><Folder><name>typetest</name>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#typetest">
        <SimpleData name="a">as</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="b">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="c">34.5600000000000020</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="d">2012/06/12</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>87,19</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#typetest">
        <SimpleData name="a">df</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="b">2</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="c">12.9800000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="d">2012/06/12</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>136,59</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#typetest">
        <SimpleData name="a">fg</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="b">3</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="c">12.5600000000000000</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="d">2012/06/12</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <Point><coordinates>165,21</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
<Schema name="typetest" id="typetest">
    <SimpleField name="a" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="b" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="c" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="d" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
</Document></kml>
```

Integers and doubles are both advertised as "float" but they are numbers anyhow and GDAL itself can resolve the schema when I tested it with ogrinfo.

I suppose that QGIS creates similar KML. Check with ogr2ogr if it shows data types correctly. If it does there is probably nothing wrong with your KML and you can concentrate on how OpenLayers can be made to resolve the schema.